# How to fix my Encryption/Decryption code to go into a text file

Tags: java, encryption, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Every time I run the code it says that the deciphered text file can't be found. It works without the code I can't modify (because my teacher wrote that we can't) but with it, it **refuses** to work. My teacher won't help me and no one else in my class knows how to code with the cipher class. I have used the PrintWriter class, and pretty much everything else. So I don't know what to do. Someone please help me figure out how to make it work.

```
package Crypto;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;

public class Crypto {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  try {
   String key = "B1LLYB0B"; 

   FileInputStream One = new FileInputStream("CryptoPlaintext.txt");
   FileOutputStream Two = new FileOutputStream("CryptoCiphertext.txt");
   encrypt(key, One, Two);
   Two.flush();
   Two.close();


   FileInputStream One2 = new FileInputStream("CryptoCiphertext.txt");
   FileOutputStream Two2 = new FileOutputStream("CryptoDeciphered.txt");
   Two2.write(key.getBytes());
   Two2.close();
   decrypt(key, One2, Two2);
  } catch (Throwable e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public static void encrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {
  encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, is, os);
 }

 public static void decrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {
  encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, is, os);
 }

 public static void encryptOrDecrypt(String key, int mode, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {

  DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
  SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
  SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); 

  if (mode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);
   CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
   doCopy(cis, os);
  } else if (mode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) {
   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
   CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
   doCopy(is, cos);
  }
 }

 public static void doCopy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
  byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
  int numBytes;
  while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
   os.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
  }
  os.flush();
  os.close();
  is.close();





      // =============================== DO NOT MODIFY ANY CODE BELOW HERE ===============================

   // Compare the files

      System.out.println(compareFiles() ? "The files are identical!" : "The files are NOT identical.");

 }

 /**  
  *  Compares the Plaintext file with the Deciphered file.
  *
  *    @return  true if files match, false if they do not
  */

 public static boolean compareFiles() throws IOException
 {

       Scanner pt = new Scanner(new File("CryptoPlaintext.txt")); // Open the plaintext file
       Scanner dc = new Scanner(new File("CryptoDeciphered.txt"));  // Open the deciphered file

       // Read through the files and compare them record by record.
       // If any of the records do not match, the files are not identical.

       while(pt.hasNextLine() && dc.hasNextLine())
         if(!pt.nextLine().equals(dc.nextLine())) return false;

       // If we have any records left over, then the files are not identical.

       if(pt.hasNextLine() || dc.hasNextLine()) return false;

       // The files are identical.

       return true;

 }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean the code you can't modify? What code did you write and what code did the teacher write?

Comment: the code below the area that says "do not modify any code below here" is the code my teacher did and he said not to mess with it. Everything else is mine.

Comment: You need to post the error that it gives

Comment: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: CryptoDeciphered.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)" this is the error I know what it means but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: But this is logically faulty - doCopy is called from encrypt and it looks for deciphered file which is only written on decryption. Unless you create a copy of doCopy without the compareFiles call, you cannot solve this, which is pretty lame. I think what would help here is to know what you're being tested on.

Comment: So i pretty much have to restart?

Comment: The code of your teacher is a bit strange: Is it an requirement that `compareFiles()` is called when `doCopy(...)` is called or may the file comparison be invoked elsewhere instead of in `doCopy(...)`?

Comment: no that is not required, the only thing that is required is that I leave the code he did alone.

Comment: Just asking because the "Do not modify" disclaimer is inside the `doCopy` method.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Why the error occurs:
You invoke the method  `compareFiles` in your copy method, which is called to copy the encrypted content of the plaintext file to the cipher text file. When this call occurs the file containing the decrypted cipher text doesn't exist but is required by the `compareFiles` method resulting in your exception.

How to improve your code:

- you don't need the statement `Two2.write(key.getBytes())`
- use the try-with-resource statement to automatically flush and close your streams
- the standard library provides methods to copy data from a path to a stream and vice versa. Have a look at [Files.copy(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) or Guava's [ByteStreams.copy(...)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream))
- change your methods' `throws` clause, `throws Throwable` is just bad design to get rid of proper exception handling, if you are struggling with `InvalidKeyException`, `NoSuchAlgorithmException`, etc, catch these when you create your cipher and rethrow e.g. `IllegalArgumentException` or a custom exception

Here is an example how to implement it:

```
public class Crypto
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte[] key = "B1LLYB0B".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        Path plaintext = Paths.get("CryptoPlaintext.txt");
        Path ciphertext = plaintext.resolveSibling("CryptoCiphertext.txt");
        Path decrypted = ciphertext.resolveSibling("CryptoDeciphered.txt");

        try
        {
            // Encrypt plaintext.
            try (OutputStream os = encrypt(key, Files.newOutputStream(ciphertext)))
            {
                Files.copy(plaintext, os);
            }

            // Decrypt ciphertext.
            try (InputStream is = decrypt(key, Files.newInputStream(ciphertext)))
            {
                Files.copy(is, decrypted);
            }

            // TODO Compare plaintext and decrypted ciphertext.
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(); // TODO Handle exception properly.
        }
    }

    private static OutputStream encrypt(byte[] key, OutputStream os)
    {
        return new CipherOutputStream(os, getCipherInstance(key, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE));
    }

    private static InputStream decrypt(byte[] key, InputStream is)
    {
        return new CipherInputStream(is, getCipherInstance(key, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE));
    }

    private static Cipher getCipherInstance(byte[] key, int mode)
    {
        // TODO Implement and return the desired cipher.
    }
}
```

By the way: Your teacher doesn't close his scanners in `compareFiles()` resulting in a resource leak.